# PHP function for getting file size and loading time for a page

Tags: php, performance, testing, yslow

Similar to my last question, I'd like to have a PHP function that can take a local path and tell me (a) how much the total file size is for HTML, CSS, JS and images, and (b) the total load time for this page.  Like YSlow I think, but as a PHP function.

Any thoughts?  I looked around and was wondering can I use CURL for this?  Even though I need to check paths that are on my own server? thanks!

Update:

After reading the comments, realizing I'm off base. Instead wondering is there a way programatically get a YSlow score for a page (or similar performance score). I assume it would need to hit a third-party site that would act as the client. I'm basically trying to loop through a group of pages and get some sort of performance metric. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use file functions such as `fopen()` with the URL instead of cURL (if *php.ini* `allow_url_fopen` is on) to get the page and then look for references to CSS and JS in its contents.

Comment: Yeah good points, I guess I could try and get the time it takes the serve the request but that's not too useful (there's no database involved here).  Probably just the file size is a good enough performance indicator for now. thanks!

Comment: You can probably estimate very roughly the load time by dividing file size with some average connection speed based on your current userbase statistics, but there's also parsing time to consider especially with any heavy javascript. How about using http://seleniumhq.org or similar to automate an actual browser loading the page and checking for total load time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the filesize.**

- Create a loop to read all files in a specific directory with [dir](http://no.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php).
- Then for each file use [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php).

**Loadtime**
Loadtime depends on the **connection speed** and the filesize. And I see that you specify that you are reading locally the files. You can detect how much time it take you to read those files but this will not be the loadtime for the page for an external user.